# build opus codec with visual studio 2005

Tags: build, opus

i've downloaded source code from http://www.opus-codec.org/downloads/ but in the tarball there is only one project for visual studio 2010, it builds well but if i use .lib on visual studio 2005 they won't work... Anyone knows how to compile with visual studio 2005?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've created new visual studio 2005 project and copied all settings, it works!